# Laravel rule validation for numbers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have the following rules :

```
'Fno' => 'digits:10'
'Lno' => 'min:2|max:5'  // this seems invalid
```

But how to have the rule that

Fno should be a digit with minimum 2 digits to maximum 5 digits and

Lno should be a digit only with min 2 digits

Comment: **Off-topic: Typo** missing `:`

Comment: "a digit only with min 2 digits" - what should that mean? One digit only, or a minimum of 2 digits? Also, "this seems invalid" sounds strange

Answer (score 155, accepted):

If I correctly got what you want:

```
$rules = ['Fno' => 'digits_between:2,5', 'Lno' => 'numeric|min:2'];
```

or

```
$rules = ['Fno' => 'numeric|min:2|max:5', 'Lno' => 'numeric|min:2'];
```

For all the available rules: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#available-validation-rules

> **digits_between** *:min,max*
>
> The field under validation must have a length between the given min
>   and max.
>
> **numeric**
>
> The field under validation must have a numeric value.
>
> **max**:*value*
>
> The field under validation must be less than or equal to a maximum
>   value. Strings, numerics, and files are evaluated in the same fashion
>   as the size rule.
>
> **min**:*value*
>
> The field under validation must have a minimum value. Strings,
>   numerics, and files are evaluated in the same fashion as the size
>   rule.

Comment: Just adding one more validation type `digits:value`.The field under validation must be numeric and must have an exact length of value.[https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#rule-digits]

Comment: It should be noted that if you specify `numeric|min:2` you will in effect be saying that the minimun value is "2" not "2 digits" whereas just putting `min:2` would only allow 2 digits. Min and Max rules function like size which takes length of string or in case of numbers the value of the number. see https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-size

Comment: I recommend using digits_between validation because validation by using min and max sometimes it makes mistakes

Comment: for validation for a number range (eg. greater than 0 and less than 3), consider using `numeric` `between` (instead of `numeric` `min` `max`).  [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#available-validation-rules)

Answer (score 11):

```
$this->validate($request,[
        'input_field_name'=>'digits_between:2,5',
       ]);
```

Try this it will be work

Answer (score 8):

The complete code to write validation for min and max is below:

```
    $request->validate([
'Fno' => 'integer|digits_between:2,5',
'Lno' => 'min:2',

]);
```

Answer (score 5):

Laravel `min` and `max` validation do not work properly with a `numeric` rule validation. Instead of `numeric, min and max`, Laravel provided a rule `digits_between`.

```
$this->validate($request,[
        'field_name'=>'digits_between:2,5',
       ]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Also, there was just a typo in your original post.

`'min:2|max5'` should have been `'min:2|max:5'`.
Notice the ":" for the "max" rule.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers, i have tried them but not worked properly. Below code works as you wish.

```
$validator = Validator::make($input, [
        'oauthLevel' => ['required', 'integer', 'max:3', 'min:1']
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter in the "Lno" rule is the type of the rule (digits), the second parameter (between) is an option for the rule "digits" as it stood here. The option "between" must have 2 arguments for working properly, an "min " and an "max" argument. In that case 2 and 5. It means not less then 2 digits and not more as 5 digits allowed.

```
'Lno' => 'digits between:2,5' // (not less 2 and not more as 5 digits)
```

For more details  look at: [Laravel rule "between"](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-between)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Anything regarding zip codes hasn't been part of the original question

Comment: Realy? `digits between:4,8` What is not understandable here?

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your answer** by editing it. `between:4,8` does not sound like it would be a solution for Fno (minimum 2 digits, maximum 5 digits), neither is it a solution for Lno (min 2 digits)